# Woocommerce product link url for simple products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

Using the shortcode `[add_to_cart_url sku="#"]` will generate a link that will take the shopper to the single product page ONLY IF the product has variations.

What if I want a simple product (a product without variations) to link to its single product page instead of adding it to the cart?

IMO, this seems overlooked by the WooCommerce team.

All I want is a generated link to an item's single product page based on its SKU. Something as simple as implementing `[product_url sku="#"]` would be great.

Otherwise, searching Google has revealed no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

Below code is for the shortcode of Product URL only and you can use it with like :

`[product_url sku="SKUofProduct"]` or with ID `[product_url id="productID"]`

```
add_shortcode( 'product_url', 'rohils_product_url_function' );

function rohils_product_url_function($atts){
        global $wpdb;

        if ( empty( $atts ) ) {
            return '';
        }

        if ( isset( $atts['id'] ) ) {
            $product_data = get_post( $atts['id'] );
        } elseif ( isset( $atts['sku'] ) ) {
            $product_id   = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $atts['sku'] );
            $product_data = get_post( $product_id );
        } else {
            return '';
        }

        if ( 'product' !== $product_data->post_type ) {
            return '';
        }

        $_product = wc_get_product( $product_data );

        return esc_url( get_post_permalink($_product->id) );
}
```